# Pointer to dynamic array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, new-operator

Suppose I have a grid of squared defined like so in a class:

```
Square (* grid)[];
```

This, oddly, seems to compile fine. I would think it would error because the compiler doesn't know how big the array is?
Anyways,
it means it is a pointer to an array. Then to initialize it, I do:

```
grid(new Square[width * height])
```

This isn't accepted by the compiler, because the `new` statement returns a pointer to squares rather than a pointer to an array of squares. It makes sense that it does that. Now, is there a simple way to accomplish what I'm asking, other than just declaring `Square ** grid` and looping through it and doing separate allocations for each column of the 2D array?

Comment: What's wrong with changing `Square (* grid)[];` to `Square grid[];`? If `grid` is truly a grid then there's no point to adding the complexity of making it multi-dimensional.

Comment: What's *right* with that? The array is dynamic; the size of it isn't known at compile time.

Comment: It accomplishes exactly what you're asking for, so what _isn't_ right with that? Note that `Square grid[];` and `Square* grid;` are identical...

Comment: Well they're not identical in class definitions. Only in function arguments and a few other things.

Comment: However, I see where you're getting at. I could just make a 1D dynamic array and emulate a 2D one, right?

Comment: @idjarn: They're not identical, except when used to declare function parameters. In any other context, they have different types - one is an array, the other is a pointer.

Comment: "*However, I see where you're getting at. I could just make a 1D dynamic array and emulate a 2D one, right?*" Yes, that's what I meant, and that's already what you're doing with `new Square[width * height]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Square (* grid)[];
```

> This, oddly, seems to compile fine. I would think it would error because the compiler doesn't know how big the array is?

That's declaring a pointer to an array, not an array; it's fine to declare a pointer to any incomplete type, including an array of unknown size. However, it's quite an unusual thing to do, and not what you want for a dynamic array.

> Now, is there a simple way to accomplish what I'm asking?

The easiest dynamic array to use is:

```
std::vector<Square> grid;
```

initialised as

```
grid(width * height)
```

If you really want to manage the memory yourself, then change your pointer-to-array to a pointer-to-object:

```
Square * grid;
```

initialised as

```
grid(new Square[width * height])
```

A pointer can point to either a single object, or the start of an array; if it does point to an array, then you can use `[]` on it just like with a non-dynamic array. Make sure you deallocate it (`delete [] grid;`) once you've finished with it.

If you want a 2-dimensional array, it's often easiest to use a 1-dimensional array, and wrap the necessary arithmetic in an accessor function:

```
Square & get_square(size_t row, size_t col) {
    return grid[row * width + col];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason `Square (* grid)[];` works is because pointers to incomplete types are allowed, and an array without a size counts as an incomplete type.

The reason that you can't do

```
Square (* grid)[] = new Square[width * height];
```

even though it looks like the types match up perfectly is just another manifestation of the bug in the design of C where array types are treated specially. It seems like `new`ing an object of type `Square[]` should return a pointer to an object of that type. However you're not really `new`ing an array type, but `new[]`ing the element type `Square`. The result of `new[]` is a pointer to the element type, in line with the C convention for arrays.

You can use a cast to 'fix' this to use the 'right' type:

```
// pretend array types behave rationally
Square (* grid)[] = (Square (*)[]) new Square[width * height];
(*grid)[3] = 10;

// the above is equivalent to the following
Square *grid = new Square[width * height];
grid[3] = 10;
```

Or you can just do it the C++ way and use a `std::vector`

```
std::vector<Square> grid(width * height);
```

If you have a fixed size array you can use `std::array`

```
std::array<Square,10> *grid = new std::array<Square,10>;
```

`std::array` pretty much fixes all the mistakes made in the design of array types. For example `std::array` can't 'forget' its size, functions can take `std::array` parameters by value (whereas with raw arrays the array syntax just becomes a synonym for pointers), functions can return `std::array` whereas they are inexplicably prohibited from returning arrays (The syntax would be `int foo()[3];`), and with `std::array` there's no need for a special array allocator `new[]` which must be matched to an array deallocator `delete[]` (instead you can say `foo = new std::array<int,3>` and then 'delete foo;')